# Magent2.3.2 Installation process,PHP extension issue in Ubuntu18.04

Tags: php, installation, php-7.2, magento2.3.2, php-extension

In magento2.3.2 installation issue : 'PHP Extensions Check 3 missing PHP extensions'

PHP Extension bcmath.

PHP Extension intl.

PHP Extension soap.

I installed PHP in ubuntu18.04 through this command 'apt install php php-common php-mysql php-gd php-cli'.

And i checked the php version is 7.2 is correctly installed.

I have doubt is PHP-extensions is already installed or not in php7.2 ,

If installed then which php.ini file to configuring like under etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini (or) etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini .
else It' newly need to install the extension?

Comment: You can check by `php -m` on cli. It will show you installed extension list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute this below commands :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath php7.2-intl php7.2-soap
sudo service apache2 restart
```